# Enviar correo electronico por java mail con JDBC

Tags: java, email, jdbc, javamail

normalmente utiliza la api de javamail para enviar correos, pero digito los correos en duro lo cual no es correcto para realizar mantenimientos.... Asi que estuve probando enviar estos parametros desde una TABLA del SQL pero el problema que no envia los correos que tengo en la tabla les dejo mi codigo :

Mi Modelo :

```
      public class ModeloCorreo {
private static String sql1 = "select OPE_CC as cc, OPE_CCO as cco,OPE_PARA as para from OPE_CORREO;";
    public List<Correo> getCorreo() throws SQLException {
            List<Correo> listCorreo = new ArrayList<Correo>();
            Connection con = Coneccion.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql1);
            ResultSet res = ps.executeQuery();
            while (res.next()) {
                Correo u = new Correo();
    u.setCc(res.getString("cc"));
                u.setCco(res.getString("cco"));
                u.setPara(res.getString("para"));
            listCorreo.add(u);
            }
            ps.close();
            res.close();
            con.close();
            return listCorreo;
        }
```

Mi servicio :

```
public class Correos {
//String from, String password, String to, String subject, String msg

public int EnviarCorreoPrueba(String asunto,  String parafin) throws SQLException {
    final String from ="car@sds.com.pe";
    final String password ="asdf32.";
    String pdfNames = "";
    // setting gmail smtp properties
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2"); 
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    // check the authentication
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
        }
    });

    try {

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat hourdateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH.mm dd-MM-yyyy");
        pdfNames = hourdateFormat.format(date);
        
    
        BodyPart htmlBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new FileDataSource("\\\\192.168.1.30\\Upload\\Html\\Laboratorios.html")));
    
        
        MimeMultipart multiParte = new MimeMultipart();


        multiParte.addBodyPart(htmlBodyPart);

        
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

    
         message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(parafin));
     message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
            message.setSubject("Bloqueo del Lote N° : "+ asunto + "");
        
    

         message.setContent(multiParte);
        Transport.send(message);
        return 1;
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

}

Y mi controlador :

```
public String Correo() throws Exception {

    ModeloCorreo rm = new ModeloCorreo();
    List<Correo> getCorreos = rm.getCorreo();
    String parafin = null;

    String[] paras;
    for (int i = 0; i < getCorreos.size(); i++) {
         Correo rCorreo = (Correo)getCorreos.get(i);
    paras = rCorreo.getPara().split(",");
    parafin = Arrays.toString(paras);
 System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"+ rCorreo.getPara().split(",") + "");    
 System.out.println(parafin);    
 }
    
    
    obj = new Correos();
   resp = obj.EnviarCorreoPrueba(asunto,parafin);

    if (resp == 1) {
        return "SUCCESS";
    } else {
        return "ERROR";
    }

}
```

Como comente, cuando ingreso en duro los correos "hola@sds.com.pe", "aqui@sds.com.pe" , "otra@sds.com.pe" envia correctamente, el punto que como es la primera vez que estoy interactuando javamail con jdbc no me esta saliendo... Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia es bienvenida. Muchas gracias de ante mano!!. Saludos!

Comment: Cuando dices "no sale", qué significa? Sale algún error? Tu pantalla está en llamas ahora mismo? Por favor, sé más descriptivo con el resultado. Por cierto, los emails se separan con punto y coma, no con coma.

Comment: Principalmente no se envia el correo, la arquitectura de mi app es la siguiente, primero el usuario registra un lote, un algoritmo verifica las variables de dicho lote y en caso que no cumpla con las reglas se envia correo a xxxx usuarios. La inserción como la regla cumplen, puesto cuando pongo en duro los correos ejemplo : 
 message.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("hola@sds.com.pe,quetal@sds.com.pe,gracias@sds.com.pe")); Envia correctamente.... Pero integrando el metodo del Modelo no envia el correo .... Gracias

Comment: Tienes que imprimir la traza de error en algún lugar y ver qué pasa cuando intentas enviar lo que produces en el método del modelo. Sólo atrapas SQLException pero desde el controlador haces throws de Exception (o sea, cualquier cosa). En algún try/catch trata de atrapar Exception (TEMPORALMENTE) y pinta la traza.